# What is a good way to receive test results from Selenium IDE browser extension?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, browser-automation

The Selenium IDE browser extension is great for quick and easy automated tests. However, it doesn't seem to have a way to report the results when unattended.

What ways are there to get reports from Selenium IDE, i.e. by mail or posted to a URL?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Selenium Builder](https://github.com/sebuilder/se-builder/wiki/_pages), then all you need to do is run a Jenkins instance (with the Selenium Builder plugin installed) and then you can have Jenkins send you the necessary messages.

Comment: I'm using Selenium IDE browser extension, exclusively.

Comment: Ok.  Did you consider using the newer "Selenium Builder" Firefox extension instead?   If not, you may not be able to take advantage of the Jenkins plugin to run them, but I am sure you have a good reason to stay on the old IDE plugin.

Comment: Also, Selenium Builder has "SauceLabs" integration, which is really useful for running smoke tests (in the form of recorded builder scripts) across platforms.

Comment: Selenium builder requires rewriting the existing scripts, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, its pretty easy to wrap the tests in a JUnit suite and then send an email using javamail API when its done.  If you use Gradle, you can import javamail API into the build.gradle and send the email using some Groovy code in the build script.  See:  https://github.com/djangofan/gradle-samples/blob/master/selenium.gradle